# How scroll the cursor to top of textarea content with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuejs 2 with vuetify.

I have a textarea and I fill your content in 'mounted'.
I need scroll to top of the textarea content when I click a button.
I am trying  the next code, but no look.

```
<template>.
  <div>
     <v-btn @click.stop="testScroll">Test</v-btn>
     <v-textarea
                      ref="atend"
                      v-model="obs"
                      label="Text"
                      outlined
                      hide-details
                      rows="3"
      ></v-textarea>
</div>
</template>

<script ....
data:()=>(
{obs:null}
),
mounted(){
   this.obs="My text with ten or more  lines"
},
methods:{
testScroll() {
      const textarea = this.$refs.atend
      textarea.scrollTop = 0
      this.$refs.atend.focus()
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `getElementById` and `setSelectionRange`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data:()=>(
    {obs:null}
  ),
  mounted(){
    this.obs = `My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines
    My text with ten or more  lines`
  },
  methods:{
    testScroll(e) {
      const input = document.getElementById('doc');
      input.scrollTop = 0
      input.focus()
      input.setSelectionRange(0,0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <div>
          <v-btn @click.stop="testScroll($event)">Test</v-btn>
          <v-textarea
            ref="atend"
            v-model="obs"
            label="Text"
            outlined
            hide-details
            rows="3"
            id="doc"
          ></v-textarea>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, It´s working, but when I put it into a v-dialog, it stops to work

Comment: How can I make it work into a v-dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<v-textarea
    id="atend"
    ref="atend"
    v-model="obs"
    label="Text"
    outlined
    hide-details
    rows="3"
  ></v-textarea>


testScroll() {
   document.getElementById("atend").scrollIntoView({ block: "start" });
}
```